# Spring Maven generate two wars windows and unix same application

Tags: xml, spring, maven, unix, tomcat

I have application context like this is for windows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<import resource="file:C:/test/applicationContext.xml" />
</beans>
```

and for unix should be the same just instead of `C:` there is `opt`.

My goal is on

> "mvn -clean package"

two war files to be generated, example myapp-windows.war and myapp-linux.war.

myapp-windows.war should have the windows application context with C:/test.

myapp-unix.war should have the unix applicationContext with opt/test/.

How should i set up applicationContext to make this work.

Comment: If you want to have your configuration externalized, it might be a better idea to have a relative path to the file. If you still want to use absolute paths, you could use maven profiles with [resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) to get different file outputs depending on the profile being used.

Comment: @XtremeBiker I tried creating seperate resources for windows and unix also 2 profiles in maven but when i run clean and install only 1 profile compiles and 1 war generated

Comment: You need to run clean install twice, once per profile you want to use. If you want to make it in a single step just write a simple script.

Comment: @XtremeBiker there is -P windows,unix in maven that solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is helpful to you but I guess, you can use [profiler](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to do this. It will not generate the both war at the same time but you can configure the setting based on OS family and will generate the war based on which OS you are running.

```
<profile>
    <id>platform-windows</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>windows</family>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: i tried this needs two runs to generate both, also tried mvn package -P platform-windows,platform-unix but it always runs the last profile in pom, not both

Comment: This will activate the profile depending on the operating system running the build, not the target system where the war will run..